# Change the account that hosts a website in Github Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

I have a website inside a repository in my account on github - let's say "https://example.github.io". 
Can I just download the ZIP file(index.html,styles.css,app.js,etc..) in desktop of this website, delete the repository in my account, and then upload this file in a new account ? the website will work ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your site to be at `example.github.io` your account name must be `example`. If your new account is `mynewaccount` then your site will show up at `mynewaccount.github.io`

As for whether the new site will work ay `mynewaccount.github.io` as long as no urls are pointing directly to `example.github.io` then it should work.

Rather than downloading as a zip you could make a new account and transfer the repo to the new account. The option to transfer is at the bottom of setting->options->danger zone

note: if you have a custom domain name like `myproject.org` then if you delete the repo (or account and therefore the repo) it will start getting served by one of the forks (if there are any forks). In that case before you delete your account you should contact github customer support and tell them you're planning to move the repo and they can make sure it moves to your new account.

Comment: Wow! thank you. One question: the commits will vanish or stay If I transfer the repo ?

Comment: If you transfer the commits will stay. If you want the commits to disappear then downloading the zip and uploading to a new repo the commits won't appear in the new repo

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the repo should not break the website since whoever is hosting it should have a copy but you will have "plug back in" the new repo to the hosting service if you want future changes to modify the website.

If I where you I'd first download the repo and then upload it to the new account to see if it works before deleting anything.